# "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output" while installing Python

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm running into a technical problem while trying to install Python.

After the Anaconda3 (win 7 - 32bit) was installed in my laptop, I proceeded with opening the cmd to run some codes in order to prepare for Python installation.
First I need to change the directory to where the Python folder is located, then this code was added in:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And the error in the output was like this:

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Can anyone please help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

Update setup tools

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: I ran that code actually and it worked, but when I continued with the code: `pip install -r requirements.txt` , the result was still the same.